# PNG images won't work when pushed to Github

Tags: git, github, png

No matter what, my **Photoshop CC** generated **PNG images** won't work when pushed to **Github** (*JPG generated with same program will*).

The **PNG images** in question are *PNG24 transparent images.*

I'm on Windows. Can't find much about this problem on Google. Any suggestion?

Comment: What does "don't work" mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Git sometimes treat .png's as textfiles. When you set `autocrlf` then your `\r\n` will be replaced with `\n`.

So, disable autocrlf and handle end of lines by yourself.

To disable the replacement, insert `core.autocrlf false` into your projects `.git/config` .